# Map tuples to tuples using Iterator

Tags: scala, iterator

Why is the following code does not work, and how can I overcome it using `Iterator`?

```
def f(str : String) : (String, String) = {
  str.splitAt(1)
}
var with_id : Iterator[(String, Int)] = List(("test", 1), ("list", 2), ("nothing", 3), ("else", 4)).iterator

println(with_id.mkString(" "))

val result = with_id map { (s : String, i : Int) => (f(s), i) }

println(result.mkString(" "))
```

Expected output is:

`(("t", "est"), 1) (("l", "ist"), 2) ...`

Error:

```
Error:(28, 54) type mismatch;
found   : (String, Int) => ((String, String), Int)
required: ((String, Int)) => ?
val result = with_id map { (s : String, i : Int) => (f(s), i) }
                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `(s : String, i : Int) => (f(s), i)` is a `Function2` (i.e a function that takes 2 arguments):

```
scala> (s : String, i : Int) => (f(s), i)
res3: (String, Int) => ((String, String), Int) = <function2>
```

whereas `.map` expects a `Function1` (taking a tuple as its argument).

You could define a `Function1` with

```
scala> val g = (t: (String, Int)) => (f(t._1), t._2)
g: ((String, Int)) => ((String, String), Int) = <function1>

scala> val result = with_id map g
result: Iterator[((String, String), Int)] = non-empty iterator
```

But it seems much better (to me at least) to use the more idiomatic pattern matching anonymous function (note the added `case`) :

```
scala> val result = with_id map { case (s : String, i : Int) => (f(s), i) }
result: Iterator[((String, String), Int)] = non-empty iterator
```

Comment: Thanks! But there is another issue with my example. The first `mkString` will exhaust the iterator, making the map to run on an empty iterator.

Answer (score 1):

`with_id.map` expects a `((String, Int) => ?)` function as input. That is, a function that takes a `Tuple` as input, not two parameters.

You can use it like this:

```
with_id map{ case (s,i) => (f(s), i)}  //match the input tuple to s and i
```